# Appending to a text file from a while loop

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, grep

I've been trying to grep a set of strings from another set of matching files. I first read a 2 strings from $var_list (rsID and region), and then try to grep the line that has this rsID from the matching $sumstat file. I use the script below:

```
while read line; do

        rsID=$(cut -d'  ' -f2 <<< $line)
        region=$(cut -d'        ' -f1 <<< $line)

        sumstat="sumstats_${region}_allChr.txt"

        tmp_line="$(grep -w -F "$rsID" "$sumstat")"
        echo $tmp_line

done < $var_list >> gwas_hit_list.txt
```

I keep getting an empty file (gwas_hit_list.txt) though. Probably it is a very badly written command as I am a newbie in bash. I was wondering if there is an obvious issue with this command, any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: before the `while` loop issue a `set -xv` (this enabled debug mode) and then run your script; review the output to see if your variables are being assigned the values you think they're being assigned

Comment: `cut`'s `-d` flag takes a set of characters that are interpreted as delimiters. Thus, when you pass a list of spaces, it has the same effect as passing just one.

Comment: Could you add an example of how does each `$line` looks like?

Comment: I added set `-xv`, it region variable seems to be normal (region=superiorparietal) , but rsIDs are like "rsID=$'rs123765\r'". Is there an easy way to get rid off this?

Comment: `$line` looks like this: lateralorbitofrontal rs123324
I tried to use tab as delimiter in cut, and used an actual tab instead of \t. Doesn't it work like this?

Comment: Removing "\r" from end of lines of $var_list solved the issue! Apparently I should stop using Windows text editors asap :). Thank you very much!

Comment: why not just `while read region rsID junk` instead of the palaver with `cut` ?

Comment: copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and fix the issues it tells you about.

Comment: Welcome to so, you should take the [tour] and read [ask] and [mcve].  With a complete set of test input and desired output, we could better help.